# Find any file using Main.css using Grep Commandline

Tags: command-line

I'm looking to find a file that contains main.css using grep command line on mac OS/Linux.

How do I go about searching a directory using grep for a certain file?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -rl 'main\.css' *
```

It will only list the file that contain `main.css`. You can also add `-i` for a case-insensitive search if you wish. In regular expressions a period `.` means *any character* so it must be escaped `\` to stand for a literal period.